# How is replication achieved in multi DC with RF1

Tags: cassandra

I'm considering a 2 DC configuration with 3 nodes in each DC, RF=1 and NetworkTopology strategy :

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS my_ks WITH REPLICATION = 
    {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1' : 1, 'DC2' : 1 };
```

However, I'm concerned about the safety of the data as I'm unsure how Cassandra will behave. 
Considering "replication strategy is defined per keyspace", does that mean that I will always have one copy of the data in one of the nodes of DC1 and another copy in DC2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one copy of data will be on DC1 and other one copy  will be DC2 of each row. it will ensure that your data will always available if one DC goes down depends on consistency level.

Answer (score 1):

> How is replication achieved in multi DC with RF1

Cassandra is a distributed database so, RF1 for one DC means that single copy of data will be stored within DC i.e each node will have a part of complete data. If one node goes down you will loose that part of data. If you have two DC's with RF1 on each DC then you have one more copy of data distributed on all nodes within second DC